# Exception: 'module' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mobile, termux

When I am running the code from [Github project](https://github.com/ijawpikin/projectHub), I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 600, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 413, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'blog.urls' from '/storage/emulated/0/application/blog/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid  patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: Can you include your urls.py please (blog.urls). This could be caused by a simple typo. hopefully. fingers crossed 

Comment: This is the link https://github.com/ijawpikin/projectHub  finding it difficult to edit and add the code on stack

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your `urls.py` file from your github link

There is a small typo where you have capitalised the `urlpatterns` object.

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import blogListView

Urlpatterns = [ path(' ', blogListView.as_view(), name='home'), 
]
```

The spelling of `urlpatterns` must be exact in order for routing to work.

Easy fix